# Save image stream with timestamp using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv3.0

I am using open CV, Python to save same camera Images in jpg and png format. 
I am using timestamp to save the images in sequence. My code sample is following. But the problem is it only saves one image every time I execute. What will be the best solution to save the image stream with timestamp

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time = time.time() #timestamp

def saveJpgImage(frame):
    #process image
    img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.jpg".format(time)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)

def savePngImage():
    #process image
    img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(time)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)

def main():
    while True:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        cv2.imshow("Camera Images", frame)
        if not ret:
            break
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if k%256 == 27:
            # ESC pressed
            print("Escape hit, closing...")
            break
        elif k%256 == 32:
            saveJpgImage(frame)
            savePngImage(frame)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're testing when a key is pressed and calling the save function when it's pressed. If you want to call a video loop when the key is pressed please do so! (don't forget to include the escape method!)